# Question is worth closing but its contents were helpful to me - upvote and cast close vote?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, upvotes

I often run over a zero-answer question which is eligible to be closed as:

- Unclear what you're asking - there's lot's of text and code but the actual question is not clear
- Caused by a simple error

Yet, the question also is helpful to me - for example, partially solves the problem I was searching, while asking for something I don't need. So I tend to upvote the question.

But I wonder, will also casting a close-vote promote deletion of potentially useful material? And, on the other side, is it correct to upvote question for being "good answers"?

Comment: The tooltip for upvotes on questions says, "This questions shows research effort; _it is useful_ and clear." (Emphasis mine.) By that definition, if you find the question useful, you _are_ free to upvote it. Upvoting it does prevent the romba cleaning it up, however, so keep that in mind. If the question is off-topic to the point that it won't be able to be saved through editing, do you really want to keep it on the site? (In the end, your votes are yours to cast as you wish, minus serial voting. The upvote parts falls on you, but definitely close vote.)

Comment: Imho it fully depends on the context. There's always the possibility to edit the question (if you have to time and motivation to do so) to improve the question, making it a worthy addition to SO. I would advise against upvoting the question and just leaving it as it is.

Comment: @Seth It isn't always possible to edit it into something acceptable and preserving the answers at the same time. But if one found it useful, there should be plenty of motivation to find a way.

Comment: As far as I understand this question, the issue is that a question *itself* contains useful material which can be used to solve a problem, not that there is a useful answer to an otherwise unhelpful question. So I think the duplicate doesn't apply.

Answer (score 5):

If the question led to a useful answer for you, then ideally you'll **edit it such that it doesn't have to be closed** - then others can benefit from it in the future as you did.

There are cases where this isn't practical, however; in particular, blatantly off-topic questions and duplicates should generally be closed regardless. And *you can still upvote them if you found them useful.* These are the areas where closing and question-quality are often orthogonal; having two separate voting systems at your disposal lets you indicate this.

Comment: So, upvote good cooking-advice found on SO? I'm having some trouble with that...

Comment: Have you ever found good cooking advice on Stack Overflow? [These answers are not good advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322653/how-to-cook-turkey-programatically).

Comment: I'll take your word for those recipes not being good ;-) Still, that demonstrates one of the reasons "completely off-topic" in practice has to trump "useful to someone who found it anyway": The audience is just completely wrong to get a good evaluation.

Comment: Stepping away from the absurd extremes, it's hardly uncommon to find (for example) software usage questions with useful (testable) answers on Stack Overflow that either predate the creation of Super User or just fell through the cracks at one point or another. Heck, it was such questions that eventually resulted in the *creation* of SF and SU, and perhaps one or two other sites...

Comment: No doubt. Not upvoting, because I'm out of votes ;-(

Comment: Can you imagine I could ever fix a question which I'm about to flag as unclear? If it's unclear I probably have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: You can always get creative, @TomášZato... Figure out what was useful to you and work backwards from that to a clear question. Definitely not always possible, and often a fair bit of work, but *can* be worthwhile.